# how to understand the code: to calculate the number of 1 in range(0:a)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I see a code that is used to calculate the total number of 1-bits in all integers in range(0,a).

```
int count(int a)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(a)
    {
        sum +=1;
        a = a & (a-1);
    }
    return sum;
}
long solve(int a)
{
 if(a == 0) return 0 ;
 if(a % 2 == 0) return solve(a - 1) + count(a) ;
 return ((long)a + 1) / 2 + 2 * solve(a / 2) ;
}
```

I can understand the count function, but really can not understand the recurrence in solve:

```
if (a%2 ==1)
   solve(a) = (a+1)/2 + 2* solve(a/2)
```

Is there anybody who can explain a bit it ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try single-stepping through the code in your favourite IDE/debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the number `n = 2X+1` and you want to find

```
solve(n) = sum of count(i) for 0<=i<=n
```

This is equal to:

```
solve(n) = sum of count(2j)+count(2j+1) for 0<=j<=X
```

Since `count(2j+1) = count(2j)+1` and `count(2j) = count(j)`, you can simplify to:

```
solve(n) = sum of 2*count(2j)+1 for 0<=j<=X
         = sum of 2*count(j)+1 for 0<=j<=X
         = 2*(sum of count(j) for 0<=j<=X) + (sum of 1 for 0<=j<=X)
         = 2*solve(X) + X + 1
         = 2*solve(floor(n/2)) + (n+1)/2
```

Which is your recurrence relation.

If `n` is even (and thus not of the form `2X+1`), you can use the formula

```
solve(n) = count(n) + solve(n-1)
```

which follows directly from the definition of `solve` as a sum above.